# vsftpd does not create pid file required for monit

Tags: monitoring, service, ftp, monit

I want to monitor vsftpd server from monit on CentOS 5.4 but somehow vsftpd does not create pid file in /var/run (nor in any other place).

Is this behavior normal for this distro?
How should I configure monit to watch for vsftpd, should I create pid file manually in /etc/init.d/vsftpd script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this: [monit: check process without pidfile](https://serverfault.com/questions/270316/monit-check-process-without-pidfile)

```
check process vsftpd
 matching vsftpd
 start program = "/etc/init.d/vsftpd start"
 stop program = "/etc/init.d/vsftpd stop"
```

Alternatively you can follow the guide I put together using aforementioned init file.
Created RPM to keep the system consistent across updates (via fpm).
New init file has modified service name vsftpd-pid so you can keep vsftpd stopped and vsftpd-pid running.

Remember to change your monit start and stop commands too.

More info here:
http://bemehow.github.com/2012/11/15/monit-vsftpd/

Answer (score 2):

I created a replacement init script for vsftpd on Centos 5.4 that will create the PID files:

http://gist.github.com/508889

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal (for any distro). vsftpd does not write out a pid file.

Comment: It does no my Ubuntu 9.1.

Comment: @jackhab: no, it doesn't. the start/stop script in /etc/init.d/ does.

Comment: You are right!