# monit: check process without pidfile

Tags: monitoring, monit

I'm looking for a way to kill all processes with a given name that have been running for more than X amount of time. I spawn many instances of this particular executable, and sometimes it goes into a bad state and runs forever, taking up a lot of cpu.

I'm already using monit, but I don't know how to check for a process without a pid file. The rule would be something like this:

```
kill all processes named xxxx that have a running time greater than 2 minutes
```

How would you express this in monit?

Comment: (*you should mark an answer here*)

Answer (score 87):

In monit, you can use a matching string for processes that do not have a PID. Using the example of a process named "myprocessname",

```
check process myprocessname
        matching "myprocessname"
        start program = "/etc/init.d/myproccessname start"
        stop program = "/usr/bin/killall myprocessname"
        if cpu usage > 95% for 10 cycles then restart
```

Maybe if you check to see if CPU load is at a certain level for 10 monitoring cycles (of 30-seconds each), then restart or kill, that could be an option. Or you could use [monit's timestamp testing](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#timestamp_testing) on a file related to the process.

Comment: Be careful: it won't work it there are more than one process

Comment: you can use a regexp: matchin "otherstuff.*myprocessname"

Comment: @ruX: what happens if multiple related processes match? How can they handled?

Comment: It takes the first match.

Answer (score 5):

There no ready-to-use tool with that functionality. Let assume you want to kill php-cgi scripts, that runs longer than minute. Do this:

`pgrep php-cgi | xargs ps -o pid,time | perl -ne 'print "$1 " if /^\s*([0-9]+) ([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)/ && $2 gt "00:01:00"' | xargs kill`

`pgrep` will select processes by name, `ps -o pid,time` prints runtime for every pid, and then analyse line, extract time from it, and print pid if time compares with defined one. result passed to kill.

Comment: the process runnig for **very** long time gets strange runtime (62-13:53:05), so the regexp parsing running time should be ([-0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+) - look at the minus at the beginning of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this exact issue with ps-watcher and wrote about it on [linux.com](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/148189) a few years back.  ps-watcher does allow you to monitor processes and kill them based on accumulated run time.  Here's the relevant ps-watcher configuration, assuming your process is named 'foo':

```
[foo]
  occurs = every
  trigger = elapsed2secs('$time') > 1*HOURS && $ppid != 1
  action = <<EOT
  echo "$command accumulated too much CPU time" | /bin/mail user\@host
  kill -TERM $pid
EOT

[foo?]
   occurs = none
   action = /usr/local/etc/foo restart
```

The key is the line

```
trigger = elapsed2secs('$time') > 1*HOURS && $ppid != 1`
```

which says 'if accumulated process time is > 1 hour AND I'm not the parent process, restart me.

So, I realize that answer doesn't use monit, but it does work.  [ps-watcher](http://ps-watcher.sourceforge.net/) is lightweight and simple to set up, so there's no harm running it in addition to your monit setup.

Answer (score 3):

Monit can do this as of version 5.4:

```
if uptime > 3 days then restart
```

See: [the project CHANGES file](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/raw/407b0d7c4089de4aa579a6493ac0f6049835d79c/CHANGES)

Answer (score 0):

You could work this into monit as an exec statement.

```
    if [[ "$(uname)" = "Linux" ]];then killall --older-than 2m someprocessname;fi
```