# Monitor a process using monit in ubuntu

Tags: linux, monitoring, scripting, monit

On my server I have started a service using a script created by myself.
I want to monitor that process using monit. I didn't see any .pid file for that process in the /var/run directory. How can I monitor that process using monit?

Comment: If the missing pid file is your only problem, capture the process ID in your start-up script and create the pid file there?

Comment: it was a java service.when i starting the script one of the maven plugin ececute.thats my process. when i check ps -aux,i see the process with a pid.but didnt see a .pid file.how can i create a .pid file for that??

Comment: [Capture the process ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339756/inside-a-bash-script-how-to-get-pid-from-a-program-executed-when-using-the-eval) and echo that number to the pid file ; in essence that's it.

Comment: HOw can i set mail alert for this process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, it *is* possible to use Monit to manage a process that does not have a PID file. In newer versions of the utility (which you should have) you can leverage the `matching` directive to check the name of your script. If it's running, try using the `monit procmatch yourscriptname` command, i.e.:

```
# monit procmatch orca
List of processes matching pattern "orca":
------------------------------------------
    /usr/bin/perl -w # -*- perl -*- /usr/local/bin/orca -d procallator.cfg
------------------------------------------
Total matches: 1
```

Keep in mind that monit only tracks the first instance it finds using the procmatch filter.

Your monit code would look something like this:

```
check process myprocessname
        matching "myprocessname"
        start program = "/etc/init.d/myproccessname start"
        stop program = "/usr/bin/killall myprocessname"
        if cpu usage > 95% for 10 cycles then restart
```

Also see: [monit: check process without pidfile](https://serverfault.com/questions/270316/monit-check-process-without-pidfile/285596#285596)

Comment: @user3793677 If it works, please mark the answer.