# restarting tomcat service monit

Tags: tomcat, service, monit

I have a Tomcat service running that fail sometimes - I did not find the reason yet. In the Catalina log I see the following:

```
Feb 03, 2022 10:54:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Feb 03, 2022 10:54:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
Feb 03, 2022 10:54:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 03, 2022 10:54:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
```

which gives no information about root cause.

When I try to see the service status:

```
$sudo -E service tomcatd status
tomcatd dead but pid file exists
```

I want to write simple monit script that will monitor this behaviour and restart tomcatd in case it happens, but I did not find any example to such a situation. Any idea?

Comment: Could you attach the full log or at least 20-30 more lines before `Stopping service Catalina`?

Comment: why is it relevant?

Comment: To solve the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this try below.

```
kill -9 pid
ps -eaf|grep pid
service service-name restart
```

Now for monit you have to write script to check the logs and pid and execute the desired action.

Some examples are below

[Monitor a process using monit in ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/637470/monitor-a-process-using-monit-in-ubuntu)

[monit: check process without pidfile](https://serverfault.com/questions/270316/monit-check-process-without-pidfile)

To know the root cause you have to either run in debug mode or if you already running check the logs what happen before process die or become non-functional.

Comment: monit can't do 'service service-name restart'?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713187/monit-restart-service-how-do-i-know-when-its-done-restarting if that help.